# How to click 'div' with role 'option'? jquery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm trying to simulate click on element with jQuery

```
$('.select2-result-label')[0]
```

---

```
<div class= "seelct2-result-label" id="select2-result-label-8" role="options"> 
    Britanny Barton
</div>
```

How can I do it?

Comment: `$('.select2-result-label[role="options"]').click()`

Comment: Or you can use `$('.select2-result-label').trigger("click");`

Comment: @ArunPJohny, It doesn't work for me

Comment: @MaryDear - do you have any click event handler for that div ?

Comment: @MaryDear Wrap the code with a DOM-ready-handler: `$(function(){/*your code*/});`

Comment: @ThinkDifferent, there are 3 elements, I need click on first

Comment: @AlokSwain No. I haven't

Comment: Try this `$('.select2-result-label:first-child').trigger("click");`

Comment: @MaryDear then use `.first()` or `.eq(0)`

Comment: @MaryDear - If you have a click event handler already present for the div then that code should get executed when you trigger a click on that element. If you do not have any click event binded then the click event gets triggered but there is nothing to execute in response to a click event, so you might not see any changes. If you do not have any click event bound to the element then what should happen if that element is clicked ?

Comment: @AlokSwain So, I have select2 input, where I type 3 characters and get dropdown with list of resuls. Then I have to ckick on first element    ant set it value to select2 field

Answer (score 5):

You need this

```
$( "div[role='options']" ).click(function(){
//do your stuff here using this keyword
});
```

or

```
$( "div[role='options']" ).click(); //to trigger click
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to trigger click for `div` with class `'select2-result-label'` and role `'options'`,then try this :

```
$('.select2-result-label[role="options"]').click()
```

or

```
$('.select2-result-label[role="options"]').trigger('click')
```

and make sure that you have click event as shown below :

```
$( '.select2-result-label[role="options"]' ).click(function(){
  ......
});
```

EDIT :(as per OP comment want to click only for first element)

```
 $('.select2-result-label[role="options"]:first').trigger('click')
```

Comment: This method is a shortcut for .on( "click", handler ) in the first two variations, and .trigger( "click" ) in the third. The click event is sent to an element when the mouse pointer is over the element, and the mouse button is pressed and released.

Answer (score 1):

**HTML:**

```
<div class= "seelct2-result-label" id="select2-result-label-8" role="options"> Test1-Role Options__0</div>

<div class= "seelct2-result-label" id="select2-result-label-81" role="options__1"> Test2-Role options__1</div>

<div class= "seelct2-result-label" id="select2-result-label-82" role="options"> Test3-Role options</div>
```

**Some CSS just for more clarification:**

```
div { background:#999; color:#fff; padding:10px;width:20%; margin-bottom:10px;}
```

**jQuery Code:**

```
$('.seelct2-result-label').on('click', function() {
  var roleOption = $.trim($(this).attr('role'));
  if(roleOption == 'options') {
    alert('The div with role options is clicked');
  }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5zde215g/)